# How to trigger again with button click using v-once

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a button like below.

```
 <button v-on:click.once="Search">
    <span>Search</span>
 </button>

 methods: {
    Search(){
       const result =  axios.get('url')
       return result
    }
 }
```

It works well when I click once and it's waiting a result, even though it's clicked many times before having the result.
But after getting it, I want to click again. But it doesn't work at all. How can I control this problem? Thank you so much for reading it.

Comment: Why you are using v-on:click.once if you want to click multiple times?

<!-- the click event will be triggered at most once -->
<a v-on:click.once="doThis"></a>